# UICollectionView inside UICollectionViewCell - empty area cancels touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` (A) with photo gallery thumbnails inside a `UICollectionViewCell` of another `UICollectionView`(B).

**I'd like to achieve this behavior:**

- when a user **taps on the thumbnail** (A's cell), detail of the photo is opened (no
  problem here)
- when a user **taps on empty space** of the `UICollectionView` (A) I'd like to open (B) cell detail. *But* the empty area of the `UICollectionView` (A) cancels user touches and doesn't forward them to the (B) cell.

**I have:**

```
_collectionView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
_collectionView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

and using autolayout.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it is an "empty" area why would there be a cell?  That's not making any sense.  The empty area of a cv contains no cells.

Comment: Because the whole CL area is inside another UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: try attaching a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the embedded `UICollectionView` (maybe you'll have to set recognizer's `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` to make delegate callback work).

Comment: @VojtaJuice Please add and accept an answer with your solution instead of adding it as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I subclassed UICollectionView and then override hitTest method.

```
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIView* view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (view == self) {

        return self.superview;

    }

    else {

         return view;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

swift version

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let v = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    return v == self ? superview : v
}
```